# Show Balloons in stock graph amcharts

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amstock

I want to show balloon on mouse hover in stock amcharts but its not working somehow , I have set three properties in stockgraph.

```
showBalloon: true,
showBalloonAt:"top",
balloonText:"[[value]]",
```

My code is here http://jsfiddle.net/hwhpguaf/4/

Answer (score 2):

This is because the the setting is being overridden by `chartCursorSettings`. The particular config variable is [`valueBalloonsEnabled`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/ChartCursorSettings#valueBalloonsEnabled). You need to set it to `true` to enable balloons:

```
chartCursorSettings: {
  pan: true,
  valueBalloonsEnabled: true,
  valueLineEnabled: true,
  valueLineBalloonEnabled: true
},
```

Here's your updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/hwhpguaf/5/